# Connectin g a device to the LAN via Laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan

I have a device (DVR Recorder) that needs to be connected to my LAN through an Ethernet cable for NTP purposes of scheduling recordings. It's not an option to directly plug it into my router. From what I understand, I should be able to connect it to the LAN via my Laptop which is connected to the network through Wi-Fi via a Cross-over cable?

Will this work? The Laptop is running Win7, would I have to turn something on in Windows for it to work properly?

Comment: Your question doesn't show research effort. There are at least two general ways to do what you want: *network bridge* and *Internet Connection Sharing*. "It's not an option to directly plug it into my router" – why? Your reasons are important because e.g. some of them may rule out bridging.

Comment: If it's about NTP only, consider running NTP server on your laptop. If you can make your device use it then a separate connection between the device and laptop will be enough. This follows the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).